# Hibernate: LazyLoading - Search by Object in One-To-Many Collection

Tags: performance, hibernate, join, associations, one-to-many

I got an Entity 1 -> SubEntity n One-To-Many-relation.

I just would like to check, if this is the *most efficient* way **to search for an Entity, including a specified SubEntity in its "One-To-Many-Collection"**. It works, but do I have to join fetch the SubEntities or is there a **more lightweight** solution if I don't need all SubEntities to be loaded? (FetchMode = Lazy)

```
public Entity getEntityBySubEntity(SubEntity subEntity) { 
     List<Entity> result = (List<Entity>)getHibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(
         "From Entity as e left join fetch e.subEntities as sub where sub.id = :id","id",subEntity.getId()); 
     if (!result.isEmpty()) { 
          return result.get(0);
     } else {
          throw new NoResultException();
     }
 }
```

(by the way, there should always be just one result...)

thx in adv,

cav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine, but needlessly fetches the subEntities. Just remove the fetch keyword. And since the sub-entity can't be null to satisfy the condition, an inner join is OK:

```
select e from Entity e inner join e.subEntities sub where sub.id = :id
```

Comment: thanks! but a pure change like this won't work, since this query does not return a List<Entity>, but a List of Arrays of [0] = Entity-Object [1] = SubEntity-Object. Am I right, that its more lightweight, since it doesnt return your Entity-Object with all of its SubEntities, but just the Entity-Object and its specific SubEntity-Object that has the id, I search for? i think a "return result.get(0)[0]; would do the tricK!?

Comment: ..naturally and changing the type of "result" to List<Object[]>. I would prefere to use my own List<AbstractEntity[]>, due to the fact that i personally dislike using Object...but this isnt possible, is it?

Comment: The query in my answer returns a List<Entity>. It starts with `select e`, so the result is a list of `e`, `e` being the alias of `Entity`.